# Date range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select the data from a table ranging between current month till next 12 months. But I don't have a date column in the data. The date is divided in three parts - CalDay, CalMonth and CalYear.

I have tried below query:

```
SELECT CustomerName, CalDay, CalMonth, CalYear, RequiredHours
FROM [DLSizingDB].[dbo].[SMTRequiredHours]
WHERE       
    CalYear >= (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())) AND 
    CalYear <= (SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,12,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))) AND
    CalMonth >= (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()))
    AND SiteCode = 'MX01'
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

It selects the data till 2016 Dec only. I need to select Jan 2017 as well. How to achieve this?

Sample Data

```
CustomerName     CalDay     CalMonth     CalYear     RequiredHours
"ACFG"           1          2            2016        10
"AZS"            1          3            2016        20
"AZW"            1          4            2016        20
"AZG"            1          5            2016        20
"AZJ"            1          6            2016        20
"AZL"            1          1            2017        20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement takes CalDay into account as well. This selects all entries for which the date is in the range [current_date, current_date + one year).

```
SELECT CustomerName, CalDay, CalMonth, CalYear, RequiredHours
FROM [DLSizingDB].[dbo].[SMTRequiredHours]
WHERE
    SiteCode = 'MX01' AND (
        calyear=YEAR(GETDATE())   AND (calmonth>MONTH(GETDATE()) OR calmonth=MONTH(GETDATE()) AND calday>=DAY(GETDATE())) OR
        calyear=YEAR(GETDATE())+1 AND (calmonth<MONTH(GETDATE()) OR calmonth=MONTH(GETDATE()) AND calday< DAY(GETDATE()))
    )
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

---

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
SELECT CustomerName, CalDay, CalMonth, CalYear, RequiredHours
FROM [DLSizingDB].[dbo].[SMTRequiredHours]
WHERE
    SiteCode = 'MX01' AND 
    DATEFROMPARTS(calyear,calmonth,calday) BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(YEAR,1,GETDATE())) AS DATE)
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work...

```
SELECT CustomerName, CalDay, CalMonth, CalYear, RequiredHours
FROM [DLSizingDB].[dbo].[SMTRequiredHours]
WHERE      
  SiteCode = 'MX01' AND 
  (
    (CalYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND CalMonth >= MONTH(GETDATE()))
    OR 
    (CalYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AND CalMonth < MONTH(GETDATE()))
  )
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

The year is either the current year and month is greater than current month or year is next year and month is less than current month.